# .load() failing for cached image

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, browser-cache, onload

I'm following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163270/offsetwidth-width-width-etc-not-always-returning-properly-on-auto-sized) from Sept. '17. At the time, a StackOverflow user recommended that I add a load callback to my function - I wanted to resize a div based on the size of an image that it contained, in order to properly wrap a caption contained in the div, and sometimes the script was getting a size of 1 or 0 because it ran before the image had loaded. Attaching the resize function to a load callback solved the problem.

Now I'm running into the issue where the image caches and therefore the script fails to execute. Is there a simple JS solution to this? I know another alternative would be to force the image to reload each time by adding a random string to its source URL, but that'd require some kludgey PHP, so I'd like to avoid it if it can be easily avoided by editing the JS.

Here's my current code:

```
$(".main_image .wp-post-image").on('load', function() { 
    newWidth = $(".main_image .wp-post-image").width(); 
    $(".wp-post-image").parent(".main_image").css({"width": newWidth});
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you verify that a cached image is not causing that script to execute?  Afaik, cached images still have to be retrieved and shown on the screen, which should still cause a load event.  Just the pull would be from cache rather than a full network request.

Comment: I'm assuming that caching is the problem because Cmd+Shift+R causes it to execute successfully while Cmd+R does not. It's definitely that the "load" event is not happening, through testing with alerts.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j96ffcgj/3/  this appears to still execute the load event, even though the image is cached (according to my network tab).

Comment: Attaching the onload to the img tag itself would require the same sort of PHP kludge I'd been hoping to avoid; is there no jquery solution?

Comment: Right now I'm simply trying to verify if there is or is not a load event, truly.

Comment: You already have a jQuery solution ..? Though there's a gotcha here, at the time the code for attaching the listener is executed, the image might have already been loaded, especially when loading from the cache. I'm not sure, but jQuery should tackle this issue too.

Comment: I'm curious if a solution would be just to execute this logic on page load, vs image load, since if the whole page has loaded, that means all the images have loaded.  You could iterate over them at that point and do whatever.

Comment: Attaching it to window load instead of image load worked. I'm still not really sure I understand why.